# iPad Air 2 doesn't auto-join wi-fi

Tags: ipad, wifi

I am trying to figure out why my iPad won't automatically reconnect to my home wi-fi after coming back home. I will have to go into Settings and manually connect to wi-fi. My iPhone SE (2020) and MBP both reconnect without any problems. I check the settings on the iPad and they are the same as on my iPhone.
I keep my wireless network hidden but if I allow it to be seen the iPad still doesn't auto-join. What could be causing this problem and how do I fix it?

iPad Air 2 running 13.5.1
iPhone SE running 13.51

Comment: Does it maybe connect to the wrong wifi network,?  I live in a high-rise apt. building.  When I go to select which wifi network to connect to, i see about 50 wifi networks.  Most are password protected but there is one that isn't. my mac often chooses it.

Comment: @jmh Nope. In fact, Settings > Wi-Fi says "Not Connected".

Comment: What about other WiFi networks.  Will it auto join them or will it not auto connect to any saved WiFi network?

Comment: I got all the equipment during the lockdown, so I have not been able to test other wifi networks.